# Firebase : Authentication providers different email address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I register with Facebook (x@x.com) and later log in with Google (y@y.com), but I do not have the same email address on both providers, there are 2 users created. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Linking is typically used in three cases:
Automatically requested by the backend for security reasons: when a user signs in to google for example with email x@x and then logs out and tries to sign in with a new facebook account x@x. In this case the backend will not complete the second sign in without verifying that the second user is the same as the first user (since both use the same email). So in this case, the user has to sign to the google account and then link the second facebook account to the initial one.

Manually triggered by the developer: One common case here is that the user signs in to google with email x@x and remains signed in. The developer wants access to the user's facebook friends. So the developer will ask the user to link their facebook account to the already logged in google user.

Upgrading an anonymous user: Developer could automatically sign in users initially as anonymous and then prompt them to upgrade to a registered user. In this case you can call link on the anonymous user.

So auth.currentUser.link can be made on all kinds of users as long as the account you are linking is new and not already linked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Account Linking APIs to authenticate multiple providers for the same account. Docs for [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking) are available.

Comment: I wanted to make a new question on the web page documentation you mentioned, because it is not clear to me. Is the `auth.currentUser.link` method only made to link existing users (email/password) to any of the authentication providers? Even if this is the case: the 4 points are absolutely not clear. Could you provide me a code example of what you understand of the web docs please? That would help me a lot